# Setting the new domain as a domain pointer alias to the main domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, ns-record

I don't have enough information about DNS and domains. I have a domain on my host and I want to add my new domain to point to the server. I find out that it can be done with domain pointers. I set the new domain in directadmin panel and from DNS management menu I set NS records for the new domain pointing to Nameservers of the first domain. I also set DNS records of the new domain pointing to Nameservers of the first domain in the panel of the hosting site I bought the domain from. But when I ping the new domain it says:

> Ping request could not find host

Am I doing things right? Did I miss something or did anything extra?

**EDIT**

Example:

I have a domain (**example.com**) on a host which uses **direct admin**. the ip of the server is **X.Y.Z.W**

**example.com** has 2 dns according to intoDNS: **dns1.something.com.** & **dns2.something.com.**

I bought a new domain from a hosting site (**newdomain.com**). I want **newdomain.com** to point to **X.Y.Z.W**

configs that I've done:

1. add **newdomain.com** as a domain pointer alias to **example.com**

[Direct Admin Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWG42.png)

2. add **dns1.something.com.** & **dns2.something.com.** as NS record in DNS Administration for **newdomain.com**

[Direct Admin Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hERw.png)

3. In the domain management panel of **newdomain.com** in hosting site I changed DNSs to **dns1.something.com** & **dns2.something.com**

Comment: I don't really understand.. can you try to clarify with an example and provide your configuration?

Comment: @Tom please see edit. I put an example with explanation of what I did

Comment: If you want **newdomain.com** to point to **X.Y.Z.W** then just create an A record for it. You don't need to modify the NS records unless you want to change the hosting provider for the domain.

Comment: and NS records of **newdomain.com** should be the default ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave point NS records at their default settings. They should point to the hosting company you're using. If you want two domain names to point to the same website, configure those names to point to the same IP address, the address of your webserver, e.g.

```
example.com.         A   203.0.113.80
www.example.com.     A   203.0.113.80
newdomain.com.       A   203.0.113.80
www.newdomain.com.   A   203.0.113.80
```

<del>Next you need to configure your webserver (nginx or apache or ...) to either listen to that IP address regardless of the Host header (i.e. the domain name typed into the browser field) or create a VirtualHost for each domain name. In the above example this would mean configuring four virtual hosts.</del>

On your webserver you'll have to add `ServerAlias` statements so that the server serves the same website for several different Host headers.

I hope this fully answers your question.

Comment: what if I don't want to add the configuration to the webserver? I think then I should use domain pointers. This is direct admin's explanation: **`Instead of creating a redirect, the option will use a "ServerAlias" which will allow another domain to be used without the end user ever knowing the domain is setup with a different name.`**

Comment: Correct. Using `ServerAlias` is the way to go here. You don't need several `<VirtualHost> ` statements if they all point to the same website. I'll modify my answer.